# elasticsearch get unique values, and the values count on multiple fields

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to get the list of unique values from a field, and at the same time, count how many times each of those unique values have appeared in two different fields.

Let's say I have a product that can be both *bought* and *sold*. I want to query: Unique values that have appeared in the field *sold*, AND, count how many times each value has appeared in both `sold`, and `bought` fields.

The closest I came so far is `terms` aggregation I get to have both values, but in two different buckets:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "sold": {
      "terms":{
        "field": "productname.sold.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      }
    },
    "bought": {
      "terms":{
        "field": "product.bought.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it gives me the result in two seperate buckets. My ideal output is like this:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "product_stat": {
      "key": "<product>"
      "sold": "<#>"
      "bought": "<#>"
    }
  }
```

How should I form my query to achieve so? I want to get unique values of sold, and count how many times that value has appeared in sold and bought fields.

Comment: Could you please share your mapping details and provide a sample doc? That'd be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  body = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sold": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product.sold.keyword",
        "size": 40000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bought": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product.bought.keyword",
            "size": 40000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this might work. Elasticsearch times out though for size > 10 (Given that I have billions of docs)

Comment: in python: esConnector = Elasticsearch(url, maxsize=25, retry_on_timeout=True, sniff_on_connection_fail=True, sniff_timeout=60, timeout=5) You shouldn't need more than 5 seconds, not 10, I think