# Search unique values via Elastic Search in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to get unique values in a column 'description'. According to my data i have many similar descriptions. I want only unique ones.

```
con.search(index='data', body={
        "aggs": {
            "query": {
                "match": {"description": query_input}
            },
            "size": 30,
            "distinct_description": {
            }
        }


    })
```

However this is not working out at all.
Any suggestions.

Example:

```
{id: 1, state: "OP", description: "hot and humid"}
{id: 2, state: "LO", description: "dry"}
{id: 3, state: "WE", description: "hot and humid"}
{id: 4, state: "OP", description: "green and vegetative"}
{id: 5, state: "HP", description: "dry"}
```

Result:

```
{id: 1, state: "OP", description: "hot and humid"}
{id: 2, state: "LO", description: "dry"}
{id: 4, state: "OP", description: "green and vegetative"}
```

Comment: In general aggregations shouldn't be performed on regular text entries - try to create a Keyword version of field and create the aggregation on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try a term aggregation on the `description.keyword` subfield:

```
body = {
  "query": {
    "match": {"state": query_input}
  },
   "size":1000,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_descriptions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "description.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

result = con.search(index='data', body=body)
occurrences_list = list()
occurrences_dict = {"description":None, "score":None}
for res in result["aggregations"]["distinct_descriptions"]["buckets"]:
    occurrences_dict["description"] = {res['key'] : res['doc_count'] }
    occurrences_list.append( occurrences_dict )

for res in result["hits"]["hits"]:
    for elem in occurrences_list:
        if res["_source"]["description"] == elem['description']:
            if not elem["score"]:
                elem["score"] = res["_score"]
```

Pay attention at the query producted on monday, now there is also a size parameter otherwise elasticsearch retrieve only 20 hits by default

Comment: but then i also need to put 'query_input' (by user), for searching. Where to put it in this body?

Comment: I appreciate your quick wit bro. But i tried printing result["hits"]["hits"]. Its not unique.

Comment: I tried returning `return result["aggregations"]["distinct_descriptions"]["buckets"]`, its also not unique....

Comment: `return result["aggregations"]["distinct_descriptions"]["buckets"]` this is unique result?

Comment: this is not possible. Terms aggregations return unique values. Maybe there are case insensitive strings? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: could you post the value output of occurrences_dict?

Comment: sure. `[
   
   
   {
      "_index":"data",
      "_type":"key",
      "_id":"z-wBEXEBKKvNh5NvhK9I",
      "_score":5.490777,
      "_source":{
         "id":"ui00005_13629728_12.0",
         "source":"ui00005_13629728",
         "description":"Note(s):"
      }
   },
   {
      "_index":"data",
      "_type":"key",
      "_id":"QuwBEXEBKKvNh5Nvn7Oi",
      "_score":5.490777,
      "_source":{
         "id":"ui00095_22711801_11.0",
         "source":"ui00095_22711801",
         "description":"Note(s):"
      }
   }
]`

Comment: i have trimmed few blocks. But all of them have 100% same description. I was hoping for unique descriptions

Comment: pay attention, this is not the aggregation output! It is the query one, and it is normal that there aren't unique values here

Comment: my mistake. This time i was printing `res["aggregations"]["distinct_descriptions"]["buckets"]` For some reason i was getting empty arrays for all attempts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211544/discussion-between-lupanoide-and-trickortreat).

Comment: unfortunately my company is blocking this chat.

Comment: ok, have you declared an own mapping, or you have created the index without configurations? If you type GET <your_index_name>/_mapping in kibana what it is the mapping for the field description? Could you update your question with this info?

Comment: ohh i got it... Sorry mate how i didn't see this. Actually it 'description' and not descriptions' . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks again. Bro i needed the previous format... with id, source.... its actually grouping. Is there some way to just pick result with different score...?

Comment: Sure... you have a score in the query output, so should parse your query output and looking for every key of the aggregation. Then you captures these values and add them to your dict

Comment: it is normal that an aggregations doesn't have score, you should think it as a group_by in sql

Comment: @TrickOrTreat I have seen that you have posted another question... I have update my answer to collect the score for each hits

Comment: @TrickOrTreat Have you solved with the updated code?

Comment: unfortunately i didnt get a chance to work on it that much. But this is not completing my requirement. I want other data also, and not just description and count. So i was wondering is there a way in which from that aggregate result i get atleast one entire row?

Comment: With new code you could capture description, count and score. What do you mean for an entire row? Do you mean the entire document with all its fields? I could adjust the code to capture it, it's quite simple because you could treat the json response as a dict.

Comment: I added one example for visual aid in above problem... It will help in understanding this problem better. Do you think we can achieve this using ES?

Comment: I got a solution... and it is use of 'collapse' keyword other than aggregation.

Comment: Do you need something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473218/elasticsearch-get-unique-values-and-the-values-count-on-multiple-fields/60485767#60485767

Comment: Its close but not what i need. I actually needed that collapse method only, as i wanted to display unique scores